# using jQuery, how change multiple images each src?

Tags: jquery

I wanna change my image's src with jQuery, but image is not one. multiple images.

please, see my code.

**1st image :**

```
<a href="http://lh6.ggpht.com/-tW5eZaAemP8/UBZ_aT66SiI/AAAAAAAAZPM/CkVqrBISveU/s1600-h/IMGP3368%25255B2%25255D.jpg" target="_blank"><img style="display: inline" title="IMGP3368
No EXIF" alt="IMGP3368" src="http://lh5.ggpht.com/-WvsxW1qf94s/UBZ_bS1pT0I/AAAAAAAAZPU/FnSwggTLHQk/IMGP3368_thumb.jpg?imgmax=800" width="640" height="426"></a>
```

**2nd image :**

```
<a href="http://lh5.ggpht.com/-RwcbVTWo_a0/UBZ_X08TWcI/AAAAAAAAZO8/-XHPCEmam68/s1600-h/IMGP3367%25255B2%25255D.jpg" target="_blank"><img style="display: inline" title="IMGP3367
No EXIF" alt="IMGP3367" src="http://lh3.ggpht.com/-FSuZrqMVwhY/UBZ_ZMMEjUI/AAAAAAAAZPE/HAb-ACKoO8A/IMGP3367_thumb.jpg?imgmax=800" width="640" height="426"></a>
```

**and my jQuery code :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.go_big').click(function(){
        var new_img = $('a[href*="ggpht.com"]').attr('href').replace('s1600-h','s1600')
        $('a[href*="ggpht.com"] > img').attr({src: new_img, width:'', height:''})
        });
});
</script>
```

If click '.go_big', load href address from 'A' tag.
and change 'a > img's address is 'A' tag's adress.
how change image's address each?

thanks your read.

(I'm sorry, my English is not fluently.)

Comment: use `.each()` to loop over all the selected elements.

Comment: @user1479606 Why does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.each()` to update each selected image:

```
$('a[href*="ggpht.com"]').each(function() {
    var new_img = $(this).attr('href').replace('s1600-h','s1600')
    $(this).find("img").attr({src: new_img, width:'', height:''});
}
```

Comment: This doesn't do anything different than the OP's original code.

Comment: Got it. Didn't realize that the hrefs were different in each.

Comment: oh, thanks. I was big hint from your answer, 'each' method. good!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this.  You use `.each()` on the links.  Within the `.each()` callback, you get the href and calculate the new one and then find the child image for that particular link and set it's `.src`.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.go_big').click(function(){
        $('a[href*="ggpht.com"]').each(function() {
            var new_img = $(this).attr('href').replace('s1600-h','s1600');
            $(this).find("img").attr({src: new_img, width:'', height:''});
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use each to loop all your anchor tag and get new image link from there. Now find image link inside it and change its source.
Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.go_big').click(function () {
        $('a[href*="ggpht.com"]').each(function (index, element) {
            var elm = $(this),
                new_img = elm.attr('href').replace('s1600-h', 's1600');
            elm.find('img').attr({
                src: new_img,
                width: '',
                height: ''
            })
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace your code with my code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.go_big').click(function(){
        $('a[href*="ggpht.com"]').each(function(){
            var new_img = $(this).attr('href').replace('s1600-h','s1600');
            $(this).find('img').attr({src: new_img, width:'', height:''});
        });
    });
});
</script>
```